# Log boot messages on tty1 instead of tty7

Tags: boot, tty, logging

I'd like to see my boot messages in a different VT than 7.
Can it be changed?  Can I get the old behaviour - to get a login prompt AFTER all boot-up is complete in TTY1?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable changing your kernel boot params, you can add any number of `console=ttyX`. The last one specified gets 'boot' messages, for example:

```
root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0,57600n8 console=tty1
```

Kernel and boot messages will go to `tty1`