# how to print mesaage on virtual console after logging out

Tags: 14.04

I want to print a message and prevent clear screen when i log out from a user in virtual console.

Please help!

Comment: You need to edit the logout script (usually `~/.bash_logout`). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/58097/how-can-i-remove-the-clear-screen-before-login